# SwiftUI - setting "Status bar is initially hidden" on Info.plist prevents a user later on to scroll to top when clicking on the StatusBar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, statusbar, info.plist

I would like to hide the Status Bar by default so it doesn't appear on the splash screen. In my info.plist file, I have set the following attributes:

```swift
Status bar is initially hidden                  YES
View controller-based status bar appearance     NO
```

I am using `ScrollView` and I have tried to include `.statusBar(hidden: true)` to hide the status bar, but it still shows up on the splash screen. Here is the code snippet I am using:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<100) {
                    Text("Item \($0)")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .background(.red)
                }
            }
        }.statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I hide the status bar on the splash screen by default and allow the user to be able to click a hidden status bar to scroll to the top? Thank you.